# Rep changes and responses: redundant notifications should all be cleared at once

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, top-bar

With the new top bar, I get notified of new responses (and other inbox activity) with a little indicator. Likewise with rep changes. On my profile page I also get little indicators regarding responses and rep changes on the corresponding tabs. Unless I've missed something (which is quite possible), there's no single action that will clear both response indicators, and likewise for both rep change indicators.

For a top bar indicator, I need to click on the indicator (opening the drop-down) to clear it. For the indicators on my profile, I need to either visit the most recent response (to clear the response indicator) or view the rep details tab (to clear the rep change indicator).

I understand that the inbox indicator on the top bar (unlike the profile response tab) is network-wide and displays more than responses. However, there's a huge overlap between the two. When the inbox content is only responses, requiring us to take two completely different actions to clear both indicators seems like unnecessary work. Likewise for the rep change indicators.

I'd request that any action clearing one indicator should clear (or reduce the count) for all indicators of the same information.